# Getting a POST request to act like a GET request? djangorestframework-datatables

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, datatables

I don't want to add data to the database, like what djangorestframework-datatables is trying to do with the POST request. I need to use a POST request instead of a GET request because the URI for the GET request is too long (I had to change nginx and gunicorn limits on the production server, to unlimited length (max wasn't enough) which opens the site up to ddos attacks, which is obviously not ideal.

Here is the code:

```
# api/serializers

class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = "__all__"

# api/views

class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer

# reports/models

class Report(models.Model):

    contribution_expenditure_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CONTRIBUTION_EXPENDITURE_TYPES)

    filer_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    filer_namL = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    report_num = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    committee_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rpt_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    from_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    thru_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    elect_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rec_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    form_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    entity_cd = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_namL = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tran_namF = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_zip4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_emp = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_occ = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_self = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tran_date1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    tran_amt1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    tran_amt2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    cmte_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    intr_namL = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    intr_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    intr_state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    intr_zip4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    intr_self = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    int_cmteId = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    efiling_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    date_report_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    date_efiling_added = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    county = models.ForeignKey(County, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filer_namL

    def get_datetime_report_date(self):
        return datetime.strptime(self.rpt_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('tran_id', 'form_type')

# api/urls

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from .viewsets import registration_views as reg_views
from . import views

router = routers.SimpleRouter()

# Register router with Viewsets from the registration views file
router.register(r'users', reg_views.UserViewSet, basename="users")
router.register(r'reports', views.ReportViewSet, basename="reports") #/api/v1/reports/

report_list = views.ReportViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'retrieve'
})

urlpatterns = [
    path('store/', views.api_store, name="store"),
    path('stop_store/', views.api_store_stop, name="stop_store"),
    path('poll_store_status/', views.poll_store_status, name="poll_store_status"),
    path('scrape/', views.api_scrape, name="scrape"),
    path('stop_scrape/', views.api_scrape_stop, name="stop_scrape"),
    path('poll_scrape_status/', views.poll_scrape_status, name='poll_scrape_status'),
    path('get_items/', views.get_items, name="get_items"),
    path('get_all_items/', views.get_all_items, name="get_all_items"),
    path('get_netviz_reports/', views.get_netviz_reports, name='get_netviz_reports'),

    path('get_datatables_items/', report_list, name='report_list'),
]

# main.js

  Data.columns = [];
  $('th').each(function(item,i){
    Data.columns.push({'data': $(this).text().trim()})
  });
  $('#searchtable').DataTable({
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
      'url': '/api/get_datatables_items/?format=datatables',
      'type': 'POST',
      'columns': Data.columns,
      'beforeSend': function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
      }
    }
  });
```

I'm using djangorestframework, djangorestframework-datatables, and jquery.datatables (frontend). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py

Override the create method in ReportViewset

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    #self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

self.perform_create(serializer) is what access the database.

Comment: so, this made it so that nothing was saved, which is ideal, but the data that would load with a GET request did not load with the POST request. datatables said 22 items are loaded (it's supposed to be thousands), but the table is empty